# D3D9 GetTransform not working windows XP

Tags: directx, windows-xp, hook

In my DrawIndexedPrimite function i have:

```
myDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_VIEW, &view_matrix );
myDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_PROJECTION, &proj_matrix );
myDevice->GetTransform( D3DTS_WORLD, &world_matrix );
myDevice->GetViewport( &d3dvp );
```

This works fine on Windows 7:

```
View Matrix:
     view_matrix._11 : -1
     view_matrix._12 : -8.74095e-008
     view_matrix._13 : -0
     view_matrix._14 : 0
     view_matrix._21 : 8.73962e-008
     view_matrix._22 : -0.999848
     view_matrix._23 : -0.0174524
     view_matrix._24 : 0
     view_matrix._31 : -1.5255e-009
     view_matrix._32 : 0.0174524
     view_matrix._33 : -0.999848
     view_matrix._34 : 0
     view_matrix._41 : -32.4
     view_matrix._42 : 23.3582
     view_matrix._43 : 39.061
     view_matrix._44 : 1
Projection Matrix:
     proj_matrix._11 : 1.19175
     proj_matrix._12 : 0
     proj_matrix._13 : 0
     proj_matrix._14 : 0
     proj_matrix._21 : 0
     proj_matrix._22 : 1.60573
     proj_matrix._23 : 0
     proj_matrix._24 : 0
     proj_matrix._31 : -0
     proj_matrix._32 : -0
     proj_matrix._33 : 1.00025
     proj_matrix._34 : 1
     proj_matrix._41 : 0
     proj_matrix._42 : 0
     proj_matrix._43 : -0.125031
     proj_matrix._44 : 0
World Matrix:
     world_matrix._11 : 0.0245525
     world_matrix._12 : -0.00470921
     world_matrix._13 : 0
     world_matrix._14 : 0
     world_matrix._21 : -0.00470921
     world_matrix._22 : -0.0245525
     world_matrix._23 : 3.7749e-009
     world_matrix._24 : 0
     world_matrix._31 : -7.11072e-010
     world_matrix._32 : -3.70732e-009
     world_matrix._33 : -0.025
     world_matrix._34 : 0
     world_matrix._41 : -54.0003
     world_matrix._42 : 5.19991
     world_matrix._43 : 8.63542
     world_matrix._44 : 1
Viewport:
     d3dvp.X      : 0
     d3dvp.Y      : 0
     d3dvp.Width  : 1024
     d3dvp.Height : 760
     d3dvp.MinZ   : 0
     d3dvp.MaxZ   : 1
```

BUT on WINDOWS XP i get:

```
View Matrix:
     view_matrix._11 : 1.88473e-017
     view_matrix._12 : 1.68653
     view_matrix._13 : 1.35358e-017
     view_matrix._14 : 1
     view_matrix._21 : 5.6036e-038
     view_matrix._22 : 0
     view_matrix._23 : 0
     view_matrix._24 : 0
     view_matrix._31 : 0
     view_matrix._32 : 1.63149
     view_matrix._33 : 0
     view_matrix._34 : 0
     view_matrix._41 : -0
     view_matrix._42 : -0
     view_matrix._43 : 1.00025
     view_matrix._44 : 7.69183e+009
Projection Matrix:
     proj_matrix._11 : 2.37597e-039
     proj_matrix._12 : 2.08572e-039
     proj_matrix._13 : 2.37597e-039
     proj_matrix._14 : 2.37598e-039
     proj_matrix._21 : 0
     proj_matrix._22 : 1.73879e-039
     proj_matrix._23 : 1.7389e-039
     proj_matrix._24 : 8.22303e+009
     proj_matrix._31 : -1.#QNAN
     proj_matrix._32 : 1.73892e-039
     proj_matrix._33 : 7.69167e+009
     proj_matrix._34 : 2.37597e-039
     proj_matrix._41 : 0
     proj_matrix._42 : 3.27402e-039
     proj_matrix._43 : 7.69167e+009
     proj_matrix._44 : 2.37598e-039
World Matrix:
     world_matrix._11 : 3.4712e-035
     world_matrix._12 : 2.38806e-039
     world_matrix._13 : 7.95398e-037
     world_matrix._14 : 2.37598e-039
     world_matrix._21 : 0
     world_matrix._22 : 1.73887e-039
     world_matrix._23 : 1.7394e-039
     world_matrix._24 : 8.22302e+009
     world_matrix._31 : 1.4013e-045
     world_matrix._32 : 3.72838e-035
     world_matrix._33 : 7.85314e-037
     world_matrix._34 : 2.37597e-039
     world_matrix._41 : 0
     world_matrix._42 : 3.27402e-039
     world_matrix._43 : 0
     world_matrix._44 : 4.48416e-044
Viewport:
     d3dvp.X      : 0
     d3dvp.Y      : 0
     d3dvp.Width  : 1024
     d3dvp.Height : 748
     d3dvp.MinZ   : 0
     d3dvp.MaxZ   : 1
```

Onliest "correct" thing here seems to be the Viewport.

Any suggestions how to "fix" that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common situation where `GetTransform` fails but `GetViewport` succeeds is where the device has been created with `D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE`.

For [`GetTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), MSDN says:

> This method will not return device state for a device that is created
>   using D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE. If you want to use this method, you must
>   create your device with any of the other flag values in D3DCREATE.

However, for [`GetViewport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), MSDN says:

> Typically, methods that return state will not work on a device that is
>   created using D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE. This method however, will work
>   even on a pure device.

I suspect that the device creation is being handled differently on the two operating systems. As you've tagged your question with <kbd>hook</kbd>, I'm guessing you may not have access to the source code, but if you do - perhaps you can post the device creation portion.

Comment: okay. got what you said. I tried to change my system to proxy-dll. So i know that the application is creating the device as PUREDEVICE. In the createdevice part i can remove the D3DCREATE_PUREDEVICE, but then it will crash. Any idea for a replacement?

Comment: Will accept this as answer since it exactely explains why i have these problem. but still maybe someone can provide further "hints" how to solve this problem (i can even use a full proxy dll without problems).

Comment: But, what i don't understand is, why it works on Win Vista/7/8 but NOT on XP.